# Monogame smoothing out tile to tile movement

Tags: monogame

What I want to achieve is a 'smooth' movement from tile to tile. I'd like for the movement to not be instant.

My map has 32x32px tiles and my player is also 32x32.

This is what I already have so far:

*Player class:*

```
       public Player()
       {
          state = State.Idle;
          destination = Sprite.Hitbox;
       }

       ...

       public void UpdatePosition(GameTime gameTime, Input input)
       {
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.Idle:
                if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || input.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
                {
                    Sprite.Direction = Direction.UP;
                    Sprite.AnimationTimer += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                    if (Sprite.Hitbox.Y > 0)
                    {
                        destination.Y -= 32;
                        state = State.MovingUp;
                    }
                }
                else if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || input.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                {
                    Sprite.Direction = Direction.DOWN;
                    Sprite.AnimationTimer += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                    if (Sprite.Hitbox.Y < (Globals.SCREEN_HEIGHT - Sprite.Hitbox.Height))
                    {
                        Sprite.AnimationTimer += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                        destination.Y += 32;
                        state = State.MovingDown;                            
                    }
                }
                else if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || input.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
                {
                    Sprite.Direction = Direction.LEFT;
                    Sprite.AnimationTimer += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                    if (Sprite.Hitbox.X > 0)
                    {
                        destination.X -= 32;
                        state = State.MovingLeft;                        
                    }
                }
                else if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || input.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                {
                    Sprite.Direction = Direction.RIGHT;
                    Sprite.AnimationTimer += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                    if (Sprite.Hitbox.X < (Globals.SCREEN_WIDTH - Sprite.Hitbox.Width))
                    {
                        destination.X += 32;
                        state = State.MovingRight;                         
                    }
                }
                break;

            case State.MovingUp:
                if (Sprite.Hitbox.Y - (Globals.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds) < destination.Y)
                {      
                    Sprite._hitbox.Y = destination.Y;
                    state = State.Idle;
                }
                else
                    Sprite._hitbox.Y -= (int)(Globals.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
                break;

            case State.MovingDown:
                if (Sprite.Hitbox.Y + (Globals.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds) > destination.Y)
                {
                    Sprite._hitbox.Y = destination.Y;
                    state = State.Idle;
                }
                else
                    Sprite._hitbox.Y += (int)(Globals.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
                break;

            case State.MovingLeft:
                if (Sprite.Hitbox.X - (int)(Globals.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds) < destination.X)
                {
                    Sprite._hitbox.X = destination.X;
                    state = State.Idle;
                }
                else
                    Sprite._hitbox.X -= (int)(Globals.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
                break;

            case State.MovingRight:
                if (Sprite.Hitbox.X + (int)(Globals.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds) > destination.X)
                {
                    Sprite._hitbox.X = destination.X;
                    state = State.Idle;
                }
                else
                    Sprite._hitbox.X += (int)(Globals.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
                break;
        }
    }

       public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Input input)
       {
          UpdatePosition(gameTime, input);
          base.Update(gameTime);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

The same deltaTime you use in the conditions of your if statements must be used also while assigning the new position.

```
newPos = pos + (speed * deltaTime);
if (newPos < targetPos) {
    pos = newPos;
}
```

Currently, you are assigning `pos = targetPos`, that's why it's moving instantly.